# Signal handling error

Tags: c++, c++11, signal-handling

When I use my_handler as function there is not error but I can't because I have to use another method there.

If I build code below :
 **error: invalid use of member functi
on (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)**

This is my first program in C++

```
void Client::my_handler(int s){
    if (s == SIGINT){
        printf("SIGINT\n");
    // here I have to use stop_thread method 
    }
}


int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
  Client client(argc, argv);
  client.before_start();

  struct sigaction sigIntHandler;

  sigIntHandler.sa_handler = (__sighandler_t) client.my_handler; //error here
  sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
  sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

  client.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also take care what you try to do in a signal handler. The options are quite limited. Afraid I don't have a good look at hand covering what you can safely use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, a member function (a function associated with a class instance, such as `client.my_handler` here) is not the same as a regular function (something like `int main(int arg, const char** argv)` here). That's why you can't cast `client.my_handler` to `__sighandler_t`.

`Client::my_handler` has a hidden parameter, a `Client*`. So really, it's signature (from a certain perspective) looks like `void my_handler(Client* this, int s)`. C++ does some stuff behind the scenes so that you can can reference the variables of `this` without having to do `this->` (most of the time). And when you do something like call

```
client.my_handler(SIGINT)
```

C++ is translating that to

```
my_handler(&client, SIGINT)
```

Maybe now you can see the issue: `__sighandler_t` is an alias for a function pointer, but `client.my_handler` is really *two* pointers: the function pointer for `my_handler` and the pointer to `client`.

A signal handler only accepts a function pointer, not a more general function object (which is a function pointer plus some other data). Signal handling is from C, but function objects are from C++.

The only solution for a signal handler is some sort of global variable.

Answer (score 0):

@SJL has provided a great explanation of why this is not working, and offers a C-style workaround.

If you can use Boost, `boost::asio::signal_set` can be used to handle signals in a more C++ style. The [`async_wait` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_signal_set.async_wait) can receive a lambda, bound member function pointer, or any other callable type with the appropriate signature.

Comment: Thanks for type but I can't use it